# Test different composer requirements in CI/CD GitLab

Tags: continuous-integration, composer-php, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to set a CI environment where different versions of dependencies for TYPO3 and also PHP are tested automatically. But how to do it? It is working with the hardcoding of a PHP version in the `composer.json` but how to do it for the other versions then?

Having several `composer.json` files can't be the solution.

The build looks like this:

```
Build application:
  stage: build
  image: composer:latest
  before_script:
    - apk add bash --no-cache
    - apk add git --update
  script:
    - composer install --no-progress --no-ansi --no-interaction
  artifacts:
    name: typo3
    paths:
      - ./vendor/
      - ./web/
      - ./composer.json
      - ./composer.lock
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and had a look at how other bigger package maintainers do it:

Within their package, they use a wide version constraint (like: `vendor/package: ^1.0|^2.0`), such that their package is per definition installable along different versions of depending packages.

Testing that their own package is in fact compatible and that no errors occur with specific versions is done by running `composer require` in the CI pipeline. I'm not really sure how to handle this in Gitlab CI (Travis offers a matrix scheme), but you could have one build which contains `composer require vendor/package:1.0.x` and afterwards runs the tests. In a second build, you call `composer require vendor/package:2.0.x` before running the tests